# Benchmark for an implementation of the Miller-Rabin-Primetest

Tags: python, primes

I have an implementation of the Miller-Rabin-Primetest, coded in python3.
Unfortunately I have no idea how "fast" this test should be on my machine.
With my code I can test the number $n = 2^{10^4}+1$ in less than 4 seconds.
But I don't know whether this is a good time.
Can I get a kind of a benchmark?
Here is my code:

```
def rab_test(N, rounds = 40):
    if N in [2, 3]:
        return True
    if N % 2 == 0:
        return False
    n = N // 2
    t = 1
    while n % 2 == 0:
        n = n // 2
        t += 1
    a = random.randrange(2, N-1)
    u = gmpy2.powmod(a, n, N)
    if u == 1 or N-u == 1:
        return True
    for k in range(1, t):
        u = gmpy2.powmod(u, 2, N)
        if N-u == 1:
            return True
    return False
```

Comment: This would be better asked on the CodeReview exchange.

Comment: You could compare it against `gmpy2.is_prime(N, rounds)`. It's not quite an apples-to-apples comparison but it will give you an idea if the overhead of going from python to gmpy native code is large.

Comment: When I repeatedly run `rab_test(25)` I get `False` sometimes and `True` other times.  The only change I made to your code was to use generic Python3 `pow()` instead of `gmpy2.powmod()`.  Is this my error or something amiss in your code?

Comment: @cdlane I guess it's because they ignore the `rounds` value and instead do a too small number of rounds.

Comment: @cdlane Although that's a false *positive*, falsely returning `True`. A larger number of rounds would only make that *more* likely. So I guess they have at least **two** bugs.